# Do 'Chrome Apps for Mobile' use native web-view on each platform?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova, google-chrome-app

Is [Chrome Apps For Mobile](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/01/run-chrome-apps-on-mobile-using-apache.html) only a collection of Apache Cordova plugins for each mobile platform or does it intend to also replace the native web-view with Chrome based web-view ?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684414/reasons-for-porting-a-cordova-app-to-a-mobile-chrome-app) and this [slide](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1H8MPv-nB0NrsRiPl4LlPPeB3O3xQKyqlpBls2auYvN8/present#slide=id.gf3587ab8_0164) on Google Docs seem to indicate that it is only a collection of plugins. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259152/chrome-ios-is-it-just-a-uiwebview) says that on iOS it uses the native web-view.

What about on Android and any future platforms Google might support?

Comment: Not all Chrome Apps for Mobile are made by Cordova.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Not sure what you mean by that.  Chrome Packaged Apps are not directly supported by Chrome for Android or Android itself.  The only way to get a Chrome Packaged App to run on Android is indirectly, by porting it to a cordova-based hybrid app using the `cca` tool.  Another alternative is to take the web standard subset of your application and write a mobile website, but that is often not possible (hence the need to write a packaged app in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all current [Chrome Apps for Mobile](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) using the `cca` toolkit are `cordova` based and thus use the Native system WebView.

On iOS, this currently seems unlikely to change because of policy restrictions (but hey, who knows).

On Android, the `cordova` contributors would like to experiment with supporting the use of custom web renderer implementations.  This is being discussed as a possible `cordova-4.0` major version bump milestone feature, and would thus target fall/winter of 2014.  This is really just a dream at this point, but its certainly a feature that is on everyones mind.

I should note, there are a many downsides to doing this, its not all gravy.  Using a custom WebView means adding ~20meg to application download size, and means significantly more memory/video memory usage on device.  Alternatively, we could ask users to download a separate "cordova-runtime" app from the store (like Adobe Air for Android, or like you have to download a Java Runtime for desktop), but users usually dislike that experience.

Also, with Android 4.4 KitKat now having a chrome-based WebView, which enabled remote debugging and implements many modern web capabilities, the usefulness of a custom WebView is shrinking.

Finally, there is already a project that does what you ask, but *isn't* cordova based, and is *not* used by the `cca` tool: [Intel's Crosswalk Project](http://crosswalk-project.org).  Just adding it for reference.  Their wiki goes over a lot of tradeoffs with their approach.