# Are Mobile Chrome Apps just an API polyfill or do they include actual Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome-app

Are Mobile Chrome Apps just an API polyfill or do they include actual Chrome and provide same rendering and javascript quality and speed as Chrome for Android?

Comment: So, when you will develop a secure browser, you will provide access to any code within it to any third party module, do i think right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered this question here: [Do 'Chrome Apps for Mobile' use native web-view on each platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844125/do-chrome-apps-for-mobile-use-native-web-view-on-each-platform/21857857#21857857)

Basically: no we don't bundle chrome, but we do our best to emulate the chrome app environment on the system WebView.