# Does cordova webview violate csp

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, webview, google-chrome-app, cordova-plugins

Im exploring options to query my websites responses. I have looked into xmlhttprequests and feel very limited by googles csp when developing a chrome cordova app. Now I know googles webview is not directly supported for translating from reading this [documentation.](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/docs/CordovaConsiderations.md)

My questions are:

- Will I have access to pass information from my cordova webview to the native sections of my chrome app?
- Will cordova plugins run on google packaged apps?
- Would it make more sense to drop the chrome desktop app idea and develop strictly for the phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we do not enforce CSP for apps ported using `cca`.  You can opt to use it using yourself by using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src none">`.

Answering your questions:

1. Yes, via the Cordova `exec` bridge. You can write your own plugins and use them with the `cca` toolkit.
2. Yes!
3. Not sure what you mean. You can use `cca` to build for mobile without targeting desktop if you like.

You may find this answer to explain a bit more about the motivation to use `cca`: [Reasons for porting a Cordova App to a Mobile Chrome App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684414/reasons-for-porting-a-cordova-app-to-a-mobile-chrome-app/21709971#21709971)