# Running Ionic at cca throw "Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined" @ app.js:14

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, ionic-framework

The following is what I did to setup Ionic in Chrome App for Mobile:

1. Created a Chrome App for Mobile project - `cca create projectname`
2. Created an Ionic project `ionic start projectname_ionic`
3. Deleted all of the files from the Chrome App www folder except the manifest files and background.js - `find projectname/www/* -not -name 'manifest*' | grep -v 'background.js' | xargs rm -rf`
4. Copied the content of the Ionic project www folder to the Chrome App www folder - `cp -r projectname_ionic/www/* projectname/www/`
5. Commented out `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` at projectname/www/index.html since cca automatically inject it already

When trying to run the project I get the following error from app.js line 14 -

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined

When typing at the console of Chrome dev tools (remote debugging) `window.cordova` I do get an existing object, so the problem is that window.cordova.plugins is undefined.

btw the app itself does load up at the mobile and I can switch tabs, but at the Friends tab when I click on a name I do see that it got clicked but nothing happen beside that.

I also tried the following:

1. projectname_ionic/plugins had 3 plugins which projectname/plugins missed so I added them using cca plugin add ... to projectname/
2. Run `ionic platform add android` at projectname_ionic/ before copying the files
3. Tried few older versions of Ionic (desperate I know :))
4. And some other tries which I forgot already...

Anyone got an idea what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

I started getting the same error after removing plugins directory (I had a hook that was adding the plugins as part of the add platform). There are 3 plugins that ionic adds for a new project. I did not have keyboard and console ones as part of my hook.

Check that you have following cordova plugins:

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Once I added missing plugins to the ones added by hook the error was gone.

Also, if node_modules was removed, `npm install` will be needed.

Comment: Did check for that back then, didn't help... at the end I chose a different architecture, will probably try it again in about 2 months.

Comment: Just that the ionic keyboard plugin installation is now changed to `cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard`

Answer (score 4):

When I tried to add the plugin on Mac OSX the plugin had a different name.  You have to run this command in the project directory.

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

You can see the lib here: [keyboard plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not running this as an actual build -- are you using CADT?  Even if you're testing with CADT on a device you will still NOT get `window.cordova.plugins`.  Once you build the project with `cca build` and then install the apk on a device then the `window.cordova.plugins` will be defined.

Hatzlacha