# Javascript runtime error: Unable to get property 'Keyboard' of undefined

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, keyboard

I get this error when I try to write something in an ionic app to WP8.

> 08x800a138f - Javascript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   'Keyboard' of undefined or null reference.

The keyboard is launched but it's not possible to write. I added to plugin.xml the following line to declare the keyboard but still it's not working.

```
<platform name="windows">
        <js-module src="src/windows/KeyboardProxy.js" name="KeyboardProxy">
            <runs />
            <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.Keyboard" />
        </js-module>
    </platform>
```

What could be the solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the plugin like so ? -- `cordova plugin add https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard`

Comment: Yes, I did. The plugin is already installed.

Comment: check this out, might not be the same but has some hints, lemme know, I'm looking elsewhere too!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949456/running-ionic-at-cca-throw-cannot-read-property-keyboard-of-undefined-app